# If statement causing loop to not fully run? C++

Tags: c++

```
for (int k = 0; k != s.size(); k++)
{
    if (s[k] == 'A' || s[k] == 'B' || s[k] == 'C' || s[k] == 'D' )
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

I am trying to check to see if the entered string contains any characters other than these. If it does, I want it to return false. However, When I put in a string like "ABCEDF" it returns true. It seems like it's only checking the first character/index. How can I use for loops and if statements to check if the entered string meets the correct criteria and returns true/false accordingly?

Comment: the if/else is happening in the loop. It will always return true or false in the first iteration. You may want to return false after the loop completes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are really checking whether the very first char is one of those listed in the `if`.
The error is algorithmic because in order to decide whether the string contains chars other than `ABCD` you have to at least read **every** single char of the input string.
This translates to: 
return true inside the loop if you read anything different from `ABCD`.
If you have read the whole string and you still have not returned, well, guess what,  the string is only made of `ABCD`s so you can return false!

Plus, if you want to check whether the string contains any char other than `ABCD` you should check whether `s[k]!=A && s[k]!=B && s[k]!=C && s[k]!=D`

Something, as follows, should work:

```
bool otherThanABCD(const string& s){
    for (int k = 0; k != s.size(); k++){
        if (!(s[k] == 'A' || s[k] == 'B' || s[k] == 'C' || s[k] == 'D') )    
    // there is a char which is not ABC or D!
          return true; 
   }
    // I have read the whole string, but still nothing other than ABC and D
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the condition is `true` you return `true`. If the condition is `false` you return `false`. There is no branch in the condition where you do *not* `return`.

Your code is equivalent to

```
for (int k = 0; k != s.size(); k++)
{
    return (s[k] == 'A' || s[k] == 'B' || s[k] == 'C' || s[k] == 'D' );
}
```

In other words, you return unconditionally.

---

Without knowing exactly what you want to do or what you're doing, I ***guess*** you might want something like this instead:

```
for (int k = 0; k != s.size(); k++)
{
    if (s[k] == 'A' || s[k] == 'B' || s[k] == 'C' || s[k] == 'D' )
        return true;
}

return false;
```

Where you return false only *after* the loop.

Comment: @thiskidduh If you want to find a substring in `s` then use the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function.

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need loops and a bunch of if statements to do this task you can write a simple function that'll do this for you. Check this bit of code out!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// This checkString function is all you really need!
bool checkString( const std::string& stringToCheck, const std::string& checkAgainstThis ) {
    if ( stringToCheck.empty() || checkAgainstThis.empty() ) {
        // throw exception - both strings have nothing in them!
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = stringToCheck.find_first_not_of( checkAgainstThis );
    if ( firstIndex == std::string::npos ) {
        return true;  // Didn't find anything.
    }

    return false;  // Found something other than.
}

// helper functions to display messages in main function - these are not required for
// the above function; just makes the main function cleaner and easier to read

void displayCheckingMessage( const std::string& a, const std::string& b ) {
    std::cout << "Checking string " << a << "\nto see if it contains any character other than this set: " << b << ".\n";
}

void displayResultMessage( bool condition, const std::string& str ) {
    if ( condition ) {
        std::cout << "Did not find any other characters.\n\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found something other than " << str << ".\n\n";
    }
}

int main() {    
    std::string stringToCheck( "ABCADCDABC" );
    const std::string checkAgainstThis( "ABCD" );

    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis ), checkAgainstThis );

    stringToCheck.clear();
    stringToCheck = std::string( "ABCDE" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis ), checkAgainstThis );

    stringToCheck.clear();
    stringToCheck = std::string( "AAABBBCCCDDDAAABBDDCCSSRRAASSGGSS" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis ), checkAgainstThis );

    stringToCheck.clear();
    stringToCheck = std::string( "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDD" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis ), checkAgainstThis );

    stringToCheck.append( "XABCD" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis ), checkAgainstThis );

    // try a different set
    std::cout << "\n";
    const std::string checkAgainstThis2( "XYZ" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 ), checkAgainstThis2 );

    stringToCheck.clear();
    stringToCheck = std::string( "XYZXYZXYZXYZ" );
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 ), checkAgainstThis2 );

    stringToCheck.append( "8?#XYZXYSAZC" );
    std::cout << "\n" << stringToCheck << "\n";
    displayCheckingMessage( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 );
    displayResultMessage( checkString( stringToCheck, checkAgainstThis2 ), checkAgainstThis2 );

    return 0;
}
```

With this simple function you can check any first string to see if it contains any character other than the set of characters you want to check against from the second string. This also prevents you from having to "hard code" characters in if statement conditionals. This also gives you the added bonus to compare any string against a set of determined characters.